# Docker-compose up

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have made a file `docker-compose.yml`
and added code to build

```
version: '3.8'
  services:      
    app:     
      container name: backend-container 
      restart: always
      build: . 
      volumes:
        - ./usr/src/app
```

also downloaded docker and docker-compose
docker compose version : `Docker Compose version v2.12.2`
but on runing command
`docker-compose up` it gives error `no configuration file provided: not found`

how do i compose up?

Answer (score 1):

You need to run `docker-compose up` in the directory that has your `docker-compose.yml` file or alternatively use `-f` option to specify a path to it:

```
docker-compose -f /path/to/docker-compose.yml up
```

Also, your `docker-compose.yml` is invalid, I've corrected it:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  app:     
    container_name: backend-container 
    restart: always
    build: . 
    volumes:
      - ./usr/src/app
```

- the `services` block doesn't need indentation
- `container name` -> `container_name`

Comment: yeah after this command i got error
``` yaml: line 1: did not find expected key```

Comment: @oscar I've corrected your docker-compose file, see the update

Comment: hey anton thans for the solution could you help me with this error also 
```
docker build --tag java-docker .
DEPRECATED: The legacy builder is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
            Install the buildx component to build images with BuildKit:
            https://docs.docker.com/go/buildx/

Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```
i am getting this error while following these steps to build image 
```https://docs.docker.com/language/java/build-images/    ```

Comment: @oscar most likely your Docker service isn't running, you have to start Docker service